Reflection: ODBC DbProviderFactory
I am trying to obtaining the DbProviderFactory of System.Data.Odbc v8.0.0 via reflection.
This is my code
var odbcPath = "..\\lib\\System.Data.Odbc.dll";
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(odbcPath);

var aQName = asm.DefinedTypes.Where(a =\> a.FullName.Equals("System.Data.Odbc.OdbcFactory", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault().AssemblyQualifiedName;

var factoryType = Type.GetType(aQName);
var _DbProviderFactory = factoryType.InvokeMember("Instance", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField, null, null, null) as DbProviderFactory;

var con = _DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection();

With other provider the same code works (for example System.Data.SqlClient or Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core). With odbc i get null on InvokeMember "Instance". Where am I going wrong?

You may consider looking at the source code for OdbcFactory

Looking at the source code it should work, but it doesn't and I don't understand why.

Are you using the latest .NET 8 SDK? Also, System.Data.Client version 8.0.1.

I am using the 8.0.403 sdk version. Both version 8.0.1 and version 9.0.0 return null.

recommend you look at all the fields via reflection and see what's there
